# Load playlist into player and play/cue

Tags: php, youtube-api

Ok ....  This is what I am using for the standard links. Works fine as it should.

```
<a href= "javascript:loadNewVideo('MaQmyhkGNm0')"><img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/MaQmyhkGNm0/3.jpg" width="120" height="90" /></a>
```

Now what I need is to have a similar setup to load a playlist into the player.
What you get is this as a link ...

> PLsj-IEVUnJEyA7Qsiz4Vxxxxxxxxxxxxx

But from the api info I have seen, says that you need to give a string like this

> VideoID_1,VideoID_2,VideoID_3,VideoID_4,VideoID_5

So if you cant submit the playlist, how do you get the string of video id's?

P.S. I use PHP in the back. But not the ZendFramework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in either an array of video ids or a string containing a playlist id when using the playlist list type.

The relevant API call is

```
player.loadPlaylist({
  listType: 'playlist',
  list: 'PLAYLIST_ID'
});
```

where `player` is a `YT.Player` instance and `PLAYLIST_ID` is whatever you want to load.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffposnick/yhWsG/17/

Comment: That works in the embed when constructed complet, but how can I translate it to     

    <a href= "javascript:loadPlaylist('PLAYLIST_ID');">

To use as link and others as well? 
My JS file also does not have the function call in it ( a js file I borowed a long time ago off the api from somwhere)

Comment: With your code, the closest thing I have done is a basic call
<a href= "javascript:loadPlaylist();">
Then a dedicated (singular) function.

function loadPlaylist() {
   ytplayer.loadPlaylist({
 listType: 'playlist',
 list: 'PLhBgTdAWkxeBX09BokINT1ICC5IZ4C0ju'
  });
}

But doing it this way meens constructing a custom function for each link.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff Posnick -- Thanks for the code. After a bit of trying different things out and looking at how JS works a bit more, I found a solution.

PS .. javascript is not one that I have looked at in any depth, though I probably should. Never needed to as could normaly folow what was there.

Anyway, Thanks to Jeff and that snipit, I worked it out to work my way.

So I have this

```
 href="javascript:loadPlaylist('dynamicly-loaded-playlist');"
```

And the function is this

```
function loadPlaylist(listID) {
   ytplayer.loadPlaylist({
    listType: 'playlist',
    list: listID
  });
}
```

It seems to work. But if there is a preferable way, please tell.